# Why is my pagination not working after mod rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pagination, url-rewriting

Before rewriting my url `file.php?style=foo&page=2` works fine.

After rewrite it stops working and just stays on the same page with the `?page` variable at the end like it's not getting caught:

`foo-new?page=2`

**After the rewrite the page parameter stops working on the clean url.**

Here's what my rewrite rules look like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^style=([A-Za-z-]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^file\.php$ %1-new? [NS,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]+)-new/?$ file.php?style=$1&redirect=no [NS]
```

Comment: can you use a structure like: `/foo/2` or `/foo-new/2` so both redirects to `file.php?style=foo&page=2`?

Comment: @BookOFZeus Yes that's how I originally had it. But have since changed it after hearing you get more `link juice` using the parameter `?page=2`.

Comment: maybe if you precise what you want to do, it would be easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

So I translate what you'd like to do then, I change your rules and write them. Please tell me if I'm right or wrong.

You'd like to check if in the query string you have an optional parameter "style".

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^style=([A-Za-z-]+)/?$
```

What is the point of the `^` and the `/?` and the `$` ? Remove them:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} style=([A-Za-z-]+)
```

It's clearer this way and should still work for what you want.

```
RewriteRule ^file\.php$ %1-new? [NS,R=301,L]
```

What is the point of the `?` ? Remove it:

```
RewriteRule ^file\.php$ %1-new [NS,R=301,L]
```

So, please try these rules and tell me if they work, and if not, please be more specific or give real URL sample that you'd like to rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} style=([A-Za-z-]+)$
RewriteRule ^file\.php$ %1-new [QSA,NS,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]+)-new/$ file.php?style=$1&redirect=no [NS]
```